# How to order CKEditor plugins

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I'm implementing CKEditor Drupal plugins using `CKEditorPluginContextualInterface` in D8.

I wander if there is a way in which I can control the order/weight of the plugins so that I could change which plugin code executes first.

Comment: I just had a quick glance, and found [this](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/3318) issue. Based on that, it seems that there's no reliable way to do that in CKEditor.

Comment: Yes, I thought about implementing [getDependencies()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21src%21CKEditorPluginInterface.php/function/CKEditorPluginInterface%3A%3AgetDependencies/8) method but not sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, all you can do is specify the other CKEditor plugins your CKEditor plugin depends on. It is guaranteed that those are loaded first. But beyond that, there are no guarantees. Nor should there be.

So, just specify the CKEditor plugins your plugin depends on in `getDependencies()`. This ensures Drupal informs CKEditor about where those plugins live.

Then, it is up to the CKEditor plugin *itself* (i.e. the JavaScript code) to specify the necessary dependencies, CKEditor then ensures the depended plugins are loaded first.